# In ML/DL is there a multiple model layer?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I've been doing some research and programming in Keras / Tensorflow, and I was wondering if it is possible to create a multi-model model. Essentially, you'd have n child models and a parent model that weights them differently.

For example, if you wanted to break a larger model up for faster training, you could segment portions of your data and train them separately. My use case is source code analysis, so if I take the comments out of the source code and use two models (one for comments and one for code), then I might be able to train the two models on different machines.

Something like:

```
source_code, comments = parse_files(file_list)

// magic... train the models

parent_model = Model(inputs=[source_code_model, comment_model], outputs=[b1, b2, b3])
```

Is this type of thing done?

Comment: Is [StackNet](https://github.com/kaz-Anova/StackNet) similar to what you are looking for?

Comment: I don't thinks so, but I only read it a few times. Maybe?

Answer (score 1):

I found [this](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2019/02/04/keras-multiple-inputs-and-mixed-data/) after searching for a bit:

```
# define two sets of inputs
inputA = Input(shape=(32,))
inputB = Input(shape=(128,))
# the first branch operates on the first input
x = Dense(8, activation="relu")(inputA)
x = Dense(4, activation="relu")(x)
x = Model(inputs=inputA, outputs=x)
# the second branch opreates on the second input
y = Dense(64, activation="relu")(inputB)
y = Dense(32, activation="relu")(y)
y = Dense(4, activation="relu")(y)
y = Model(inputs=inputB, outputs=y)
# combine the output of the two branches
combined = concatenate([x.output, y.output])
# apply a FC layer and then a regression prediction on the
# combined outputs
z = Dense(2, activation="relu")(combined)
z = Dense(1, activation="linear")(z)
# our model will accept the inputs of the two branches and
# then output a single value
model = Model(inputs=[x.input, y.input], outputs=z)
```